# Как найти libqgispython.so в qgis2.6.0?

Tags: python

Как найти libqgispython.so в qgis2.6.0?

Comment: @Сsnare2015, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В Убунте и производных надо установить ее

```
sudo apt-get install libqgispython<номер>
```

Лежит в `/usr/lib`